# SFDX unlocked packages and sandboxes

Tags: salesforcedx

We are trying to move from simple metadata deployment to adopting SFDX and unlocked packages, however it is not very clear to us what's the reasonable way to test those packages in integration.

Is it needed to convert them to Metadata format or is it possible top simply deploy them as unlocked package to Sandboxes as well for integration testing?

Answer (score 2):

You can use sfdx force:package:install to install the package directly in to your Sandbox. This saves time by not having to perform an MDAPI deployment or converting to MDAPI format before deployment.